# who made some mistakes in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading *Arthur's Teacher Trouble*. I am not sure of who made some mistakes: Mr. Ratburn made some mistakes with correcting their papers, or Francine misspelled some words in her test. Could anyone tell me who made mistakes? Here's the context:

> Mr. Ratburn corrected their papers during lunch. "Class," he said,
>   "most of you did very well on the test. But only two of you spelled
>   every word correctly." Muffy smiled. Francine hiccuped. Buster patted
>   his good-luck charm. Mr. Ratburn cleared his throat. "Our class
>   representatives for the spellathon will be the Brain and Arthur."
>   "There must be some mistake!" said Muffy.

Comment: Muffy believes Mr. Ratburn is mistaken when he says that only Brain and Arthur spelled everything correctly.   She clearly believes that she got everything correct as well.

Comment: @Hellion Either that or she didn't belive that The Brain and Arthur were capable of scoring higher than she did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Macmillan Dictionary* defines "there must be some mistake" as:

> used for saying that you think something is not correct or that you are being wrongly accused of something

[[link](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/there-must-be-some-mistake)]

So, Muffy is saying that she thinks she spelled every word correctly and should be one of the representatives for the spellathon. She's objecting to the implicit claim that she misspelled or skipped a word.